# Mapping Result From SP To Complex Object using MyBatis TypeHandler

Tags: java, mybatis

I am trying to implement MyBatis `TypeHandler` to map the results from a stored procedure.

Here is `mybatis.transmission.xml`:

```
<select id="callFileTransData" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
        {call FILE_TRANS_DATA #{in_trans_type, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
        #{o_message_data_array, mode=OUT, jdbcType=ARRAY,typeHandler=com.component.FileTransDataTypeHandler}, #{o_batch_size, mode=OUT, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
        ) }
    </select>
```

And `FileTrans.sql`:

```
Procedure FILE_TRANS_DATA
(in_trans_type         IN trans_header.th_trans_type%type,
 o_message_data_array OUT Obj_File_Trans_Array,
 o_batch_size         OUT NUMBER) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Obj_File_Trans_Array AS  

    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Obj_File_Trans_Poll
                        (SELF            IN OUT NOCOPY Obj_File_Trans_Poll,
                         admin_id        IN            NUMBER,                         
                         message_body    IN            CLOB,
                         service_options IN            CLOB,
                         company_info    IN            obj_company,                         
                         bank_data       IN            bank_data DEFAULT NULL,
                         ach_data        IN            ach_data DEFAULT NULL,                         
                         payer_data      IN            obj_payer_data DEFAULT NULL,
                         ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS


    BEGIN
........
--------
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY BANK_DATA AS

   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION BANK_DATA
   (SELF        IN OUT NOCOPY BANK_DATA,
    account_nbr   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,    
    bank_address  IN OBJ_Address_Data DEFAULT NULL) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS

   BEGIN
```

That was the mapping on the Oracle procedure side.

And here is the Java side:

```
public class FileTransDataTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<List<ObjFileTransData>> {
@Override
public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, List<ObjFileTransPollData> objFileTransPollData, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    
    StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("OBJ_FILE_TRANS_POLL", 
    ps.getConnection());        
    ArrayDescriptor CompanyDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "OBJ_COMPANY", ps.getConnection());

    ArrayDescriptor BankDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "BANK_DATA", ps.getConnection());
    ArrayDescriptor AddressDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "OBJ_ADDRESS_DATA", ps.getConnection());
    ArrayDescriptor AchDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "ACH_DATA", ps.getConnection());
    ArrayDescriptor PayerDataDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "OBJ_PAYER_DATA", ps.getConnection());
    StructDescriptor PayerStateDataDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("OBJ_PAYER_STATE_DATA",ps.getConnection());
    ArrayDescriptor PayerStateDataArrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "OBJ_PAYER_STATE_DATA_ARRAY", ps.getConnection());
    List<STRUCT> structs = new ArrayList<STRUCT>();
    for (ObjFileTransPollData objFileTransPollData1:objFileTransPollData)
    {
        Object[] params = new Object[22];
        params[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getAdmin_id();
        ..
        params[7] = TypeConversion.toCLOB(objFileTransPollData1.getMessage_body(),ps.getConnection());
        params[8] = TypeConversion.toCLOB(objFileTransPollData1.getService_options(),ps.getConnection());

            //Company Data
            Object[] companyData = new Object[5];
            companyData[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getCompany_info().getCompany_name();
            companyData[1] = objFileTransPollData1.getCompany_info().getBranch_nbr();
            companyData[2] = objFileTransPollData1.getCompany_info().getClient_nbr();
            companyData[3] = objFileTransPollData1.getCompany_info().getFed_id();
            companyData[3] = objFileTransPollData1.getCompany_info().getPhone_nbr();
            Array companyArray = new ARRAY(CompanyDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), companyData);
        params[9] = companyArray;//List need to check
        params[10] = objFileTransPollData1.getService_id();
        params[11] = objFileTransPollData1.getSample_yn();
        params[12] = objFileTransPollData1.getSort_value();
        params[13] = objFileTransPollData1.getGroup_value();
            //Bank Data
            Object[] bankData = new Object[12];
            bankData[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getAccount_nbr();
            ...
            bankData[7] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getCheck_message_1();
            bankData[8] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getCheck_message_2();
            bankData[9] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getCheck_message_3();
            bankData[10] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getBank_name();

                //Bank Address
                Object[] bankAddress = new Object[10];
                bankAddress[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getBank_address().getStreet_1();
                bankAddress[1] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getBank_address().getStreet_2();
                ...
                bankAddress[9] = objFileTransPollData1.getBank_data().getBank_address().getCountry_name();

                Array bankAddressArray = new ARRAY(AddressDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), bankAddress);

                bankData[11] = bankAddressArray;

            Array bankArray = new ARRAY(BankDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), bankData);

        params[14] = bankArray;//List need to check

            //Ach Data
            Object[] achData = new Object[9];
            achData[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getAch_data().getCompany_name();
            ..
            achData[7] = objFileTransPollData1.getAch_data().getEntry_description();

                //Ach Address
                Object[] achAddress = new Object[10];
                achAddress[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getAch_data().getAch_address().getStreet_1();
                ...
                achAddress[9] = objFileTransPollData1.getAch_data().getAch_address().getCountry_name();

                Array achAddressArray = new ARRAY(AddressDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), achAddress);
                achData[8] = achAddressArray;

            Array achArray = new ARRAY(AchDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), achData);

        params[15] = achArray;//List need to check
        params[16] = objFileTransPollData1.getProduct_code();
        params[17] = objFileTransPollData1.getTxn_count();

            Object[] payerData = new Object[12];
            payerData[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getPayer_data().getPlan_id();
            ...
            payerData[10] = objFileTransPollData1.getPayer_data().getCompany_abbrev();

                Object[] stateAgency = new Object[4];
                stateAgency[0] = objFileTransPollData1.getPayer_data().getState_agency().getState_id();
                ...
                stateAgency[3] = objFileTransPollData1.getPayer_data().getState_agency().getAgency_type();

                STRUCT stateAgencyStruct = new STRUCT(PayerStateDataDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), stateAgency);
                Array stateAgencyArray = new ARRAY(PayerStateDataArrayDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), stateAgencyStruct);

                payerData[11] = stateAgencyArray;

            Array payerDataArray = new ARRAY(PayerDataDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), payerData);

        params[18] = payerDataArray;//Payer data need to add
        params[19] = objFileTransPollData1.getTax_entity_client_id();
        params[20] = objFileTransPollData1.getInternal_participant_id();
        params[21] = objFileTransPollData1.getInternal_plan_id();


        STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, ps.getConnection(), params);
        structs.add(struct);
    }

    ArrayDescriptor desc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("BTPS.OBJ_FILE_TRANS_POLL_ARRAY", ps.getConnection());
    ARRAY oracleArray = new ARRAY(desc, ps.getConnection(), structs.toArray());
    ps.setArray(i, oracleArray);
 }

public class ObjFileTransData implements Serializable {

private Integer admin_id;    
private String message_body; //CLOB
private String service_options; //CLOB
private ObjCompanyData company_info = null;
//private List<ObjCompanyData> company_info = null;

//private List<BankData> bank_data = null;
//private List<AchData> ach_data = null;
private BankData bank_data = null;
private AchData ach_data = null;
private String product_code = null;
private Integer txn_count = null;
//private List<ObjPayerData> payer_data;
private ObjPayerData payer_data =null;

//getter and setters
}
public class BankData implements Serializable {
   private String account_nbr = null;    
   private ObjAddressData bank_address = null;
   //getter and setters
} 
 public class ObjAddressData implements Serializable { 
    private String street_1;    
    private String city;

    //getter and setters
 }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2020-11-24 18:41:59.519 ERROR 10204 --- [pool-2-thread-1] c.p.h.s.b.d.FileTransImpl     : Error while 
calling poll file transmission procedure : org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
### The error may exist in mybatis-pollfiletransmission.xml
### The error may involve com.dao.FileTransmMapper.callFileTransmission
### The error occurred while executing a query
### SQL: {call FILE_TRANS_DATA ( ?,         ?, ?         ) }
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: For `OUT` parameters, MyBatis calls type handler's `getParameter` method while the code you posted is for `setParameter` method. This [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56834806) might help (it uses newer API as `STRUCT` is deprecated). If you could share a complete project which replicates the exception on your GitHub repo, I or someone may be able to find the problem.

Comment: That's a _lot_ of code. Can you provide a [mcve], emphasis on "minimal"?

Comment: Hi Chris,
Thank you for valuable information, As per my requirement SP is returning Object as OUT parameter and in that object has so many child objects. 
Now as per your information I should use getParmeter method, Can you please provide is there any other example.

Comment: Hi Chris, Can you please help if possible.

Comment: Hi Chris/Team,
Now I am able to call the SP and getting response also . But among 2 OUT values getting only one OUT values(o_batch_size). I should get o_message_data_array also but not getting. I think it was not correct while converting Oracle object to java object. Please see the console logs:                                                                                                   
size======>100
c.p.h.s.b.d.PollFileTransmissionImpl     : callPollFileTransmission Response[ ]

Comment: @vijaya4suresh I would be happy to take a look if you provide an executable demo project like [this](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/blob/master/so-56834806) and share it on your GitHub repo.